# SqlDependency can fire on localhost not remote server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqldependency

In my project which is on the localhost named SQL Server 2014, can fire `SqlDependency`'s `OnChange()` event. However when I publish to a remote server, running SQL Server 2016, it does not fire `OnChange()` event when database changes and I did not get any error.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What you are asking is too broad to get an answer.